# Uploading an HTML5 app to the Software Center

Tags: software-center

I have an app written in HTML and JavaScript, suitable for distribution in the [Chrome Web Store](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/) as a [packaged app](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html). (You can even package it up as a single HTML file with data: URIs.)

Is it possible for me to submit an app like this to the Ubuntu Software Center? If so, how?

Comment: I suppose you had to package it to be dpkg with compatible. For better reference see http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/.

Answer (score 1):

Try here: 
http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

Comment: That's where I'd go to upload an app in general. They suggest writing an app in Python. But what about apps written in HTML5?